# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' in python

Tags: python

I need to run a script where I have to change the date of the day in several fields in the code, but I'm having trouble for the script to get the date of the day alone, it only gets the date manually in this format:

```
import datetime as date  

Data_inicio = dt.date(2020,3, 1) #Ano, mês, Dia #here
Data_Fim =    dt.date(2021,10,29)
```

I tried to change the code this way:

```
import datetime as date  

data = date.datetime.now()
data_today = data.strftime("%Y,%m,%d")
Data_inicio = dt.date(2020,3, 1) 
Data_Fim = dt.date(data_today)
```

or

```
Data_Fim = data_today
```

The following error occurs in `data_fim`:

```
files=glob.glob(url+'/*'+Data_inicio.strftime("%d%b%Y")+'-'+Data_Fim.strftime("%d%b%Y")+'.txt')
files_inativos =glob.glob(url_inativos+'/*'+ '.txt')
files = files + files_inativos


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: you should've done like `import datatime as datetime` instead of `import datatime as date`

Comment: Is it really `datatime` ? I think it should be `datetime`

Comment: `strftime` is used to **format** datetime objects, so it take you from `datetime` to `str`. While `strptime` is used to **parse** strings into datetime objects, so it takes you the opposite way.
In your case, you're trying to create a `date` from a string in `Data_Fim`, but a string cannot be formatted into datetime, it can only be parsed. To create from a string, use `strptime`

Comment: Please fix your import statements to use the correct modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that only thing you want is to set an "end date" variable as your `data_today`, but as a `datetime` object, not a string. The problem is that you're trying to do that directly from a string, but strings don't have the methods for date and time conversions. In order to use those, you can use `datetime.strptime()`, such as:

```py
from datetime import datetime 

date_today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
start_date = datetime(2020, 3, 1)
end_date = datetime.strptime(date_today, "%Y, %m, %d")
```

This creates a string for "today" (named `date_today`), creates a `datetime` object for the starting date (named `start_date`), then creates an end date variable (`end_date`), that actually is parsed from an existing string. Specifically in this case, this string is the one we just created (`date_today`).

Note that this example has mostly teaching purposes, as it makes little sense to create a string of "today" from `datetime` and then parsing it *back* to a `datetime` object. The parsing of `end_date` would make much more sense if you were getting `date_today` from elsewhere, but with a known format, in which case you can parse it to a `datetime` object and use it. However, you don't really have use for a string representation of "today" in the same context.

If it is the case in which you are defining them in the same context, then probably you don't need 2 variables at all, and you could use only the `datetime` object. Whenever you need to print it or show it as a string, you can format it for that specific output. Such as:

```py
from datetime import datetime 

start_date = datetime(2020, 3, 1)
end_date = datetime.today()

print(end_date.strftime("%Y, %m, %d"))
>>> 2021, 10, 29
```

Note that if you're handling dates and times, it is usually a better approach to just use the `datetime` objects, and format them whenever an output string is required. Saves a lot of work and back and forth format-parse-format-parse stuff. Also, it enables you to take advantage of [time deltas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a `datetime` object then struggling to extract a portion of that object (just the `date` portion). You can solve this by instantiating a `date` or `datetime` object and extracting the attributes you want:

```py
import datetime

# Using date objects
start_date = datetime.date(year=2020, month=3, day=1)
end_date = datetime.date.today()

# Using datetime objects (will include hours, minutes, seconds...)
start_date = datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=1)
end_date = datetime.datetime.today()

# You can format either object with the `.strftime()` method
date_now = datetime.date.today()
datetime_now = datetime.date.today()

for dt in [date_now, datetime_now]:
    # format and print
    print(dt.strftime('%Y,%m,%d'))
    
    # Or access the attributes directly
    print([dt.year, dt.month, dt.day])
```

Comment: thanks, I was racking my brain to solve.